# How to detect if IE access my site as a trusted site?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, settings

Is it possible to determine whether my web site is being accessed as a trusted site?  In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251696/best-way-to-readset-ie-options) we determined that, in general, it is not prudent to have visibility to client IE settings.  Would this qualify as an exception?

The reason I'd like to do this is that some functions won't work unless the site is being accessed as a trusted site (e.g. client-side sendmail -- don't ask), and I'd like to be able to warn users.  Despite many warnings in the pages, many users still don't read, and send us nastygrams.  We'd like to reduce the email volume by detecting this condition and flashing a big warning that basically says "**You didn't read the warnings, and what you're trying to do won't work until you change your settings!**"  Any ideas are welcome.

EDIT: In our shop, client-side sendmail only works if the site is trusted, and I can't change that due to security requirements, nor can I switch to server-side sendmail.  However, this is not the only reason that client-side sendmail will fail, so I can't simply catch a sendmail error to determine this.  Also, I don't want this to degrade to a sendmail discussion.

Comment: First, can you provide some sample code for this?  I fail to see how a try/catch won't solve it. Second, I know you don't want a war on technology/implementation, but can we ask why you are trying to send email this way?  It seems like the least stable option.

Comment: The application supports a part of a change authorization mechanism for multiple Sarbanes-Oxley-sensitive applications.  The security folks insist that client-side sendmail is the only way to prevent spoofing the sender address.  No argument is going to change their minds.

Comment: @Ken Paul, have u got any idea about the detecting trusted site...please I need also...

Comment: @SJnawali, No answers yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a test you could use:

```
function isTrustedIE(){
    try{
        var test=new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    }
    catch(e){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This will, of course, fail if the user has disabled that particular object, even on a trusted site.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work.  In both a trusted and non-trusted site, it returned true for me.  I think you have a different set of differences between trusted and untrusted zones as compared to me (and my typical users).

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding this is not possible but you may have some luck testing for a more specific condition, such as the availability of the specific technology or technologies you need.  What type of requirements does your client code place on the browser (ActiveX, Java, scripting etc)?  Knowing that will be a very good start toward figuring out how to test the client browser for the environment required by your client code.

Comment: I added an explanation of the failing technology in the question.  I'm not sure that helps, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for the username of the currently logged on user, if you get it you will know the site is in the "Trusted Sites" or "Local Intranet" zones.

Comment: I'm working on testing this, and will report results.  Thank you - this looks hopeful.

Comment: This didn't help.  People are so used to accepting the ActiveX warning that I was able to open a WShell.Script object regardless of whether the site was trusted.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, a good way to deal with this, while still supporting unusual combinations, is to test whether or not a specific behavior was successful.

For example, if you need to do

```
a.innerHTML = "abc";
```

then you could check whether or not the innerHTML was changed. Unfortunately, I can not assure you that all features are detectable.
Also, try...catch statements may be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation (where the specific issue you're dealing with is a sendmail fail), I'd still suggest catching the sendmail fail, but then giving a somewhat more general answer.  "Your mail has failed.  It might have failed for any of the following reasons" and then throw in a bulleted list, with "didn't make this site trusted" nice and bold at the top.  If sendmail is failing for reasons other than having your site untrusted, your users might need to know about that too, after all.